# Deploy - Web page code - Back4app

Tags: parse-platform, back4app

How to deploy my webpage code to back4app, the code has some web end process.So I have to access my created webpage globally how to achieve that

Answer (score 2):

You have two different ways to upload your webpage code:
1) Using dashboard: Sign in Back4app -> click in your app features -> cloud code -> there is an upload button
2) Using CLI: http://docs.back4app.com/docs/integrations/command-line-interface/

Static files (like html, css, js) should be placed in a folder called "public".

If you want to use Node.js/Express.js application to build a dynamic web-page, you have to create your endpoints in a file called "app.js":
http://docs.back4app.com/docs/integrations/webhosting-back4app/